# laravel retrive old() wherein query values

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 2 multiple value select lists that I pass users between them using jquery.

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="ListAllUsers" class="form-control">
                    @foreach ($users as $user)
                        <option class="content" value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>

<select name="user_id[]" required multiple="multiple" id="SelectedUsers" class="form-control">
                    @if (!empty(old('user_id')) && $create_form)
                        @foreach ($old_value_users as $old_user)
                            <option class="content" value="{{ $old_user->id }}">{{ $old_user->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                </select>
```

Now, my issue is that when I go and pass the old('user_id') value in the whereIn query, I only get the first result of the array instead of all of the results that are passed in.

```
$old_users_id = [old('user_id')];
$old_value_users = User::whereIn('id', $old_users_id)->get();
```

If I replace `$old_users_id = [old('user_id')]` with `$old_users_id = [1,2,3],` it works like a charm. I have `dd(old('user_id'))` and it is indeed an array, so I do not understand what is the hick-up!

Comment: could you please add the data of ```dd(old('user_id'))``` also here

Comment: [
  [
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "9",
    "10",
    "12"
  ]
]

Comment: It's just an array of the user id values from the options.

Comment: it not a single array. its a array or array. see there are  [ [ ] ] . you  need to remove on opening closing bracket

Comment: it should be like this ```[ "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "12" ] ```

Comment: what would be the output if you try like this ```$old_value_users = User::whereIn('id', [ "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "12" ])->get();```

Comment: Yes! And in theory it is that, but in the code it does not react as intended. It always gets me the first result and not all of them! The issues might be somewhere in the whereIn function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `old('user_id')` is an array, you should not put it in an array. Try this;

> You shold provide an empty array if old('user_id') is null.

```
$old_users_id = old('user_id')?old('user_id'):[];
$old_value_users = User::whereIn('id', $old_users_id)->get();
```

**+ point**

Instead of `whereIn` try with `whereIntegerInRaw` if you are adding a large array of integer bindings to your query.For more check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Comment: If I try without the [] I get this error:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, null given, called in E:\laravel\meetings-5.8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php on line 870

Comment: I suppose something in whereIn does not see it as an array without the [], but the issue is that it only gets me the first result from the array, when I wrap it in the square brackets, and not all of them!

Comment: ok i edited my answer with considering old value might be null.

Comment: above code can be shorten more like this ```User::whereIn('id', old('user_id') ?? [])->get();```